# Adding objects from array to view later on in NSTableView?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, arrays

I'm totally stumped here I have no idea whats going on below is the code I wrote to just go through the array and print out all the other array values within the property list:

```
for (userFoodDataArray in userFoodDataArray){
NSLog(@"%@", userFoodDataArray);
}
```

What I'm trying to do "I THINK" is add them as objects so later on I can view them through a search or maybe an NSTableView could someone please head me in the right direction for what I need to do.

Also when i use that NSLog statement the format of how the print out is odd see below:

```
2014-01-23 21:45:40.212 Carbies[4425:70b] (
Coconut
)
2014-01-23 21:45:40.212 Carbies[4425:70b] (
Watermelon
)
2014-01-23 21:45:40.212 Carbies[4425:70b] (
Egg
)
```

they have these weird brackets around them why?

Comment: Post your _real_, _compilable_ code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not into the real object, just NSLog way to print the `NSArray` object collection.

When you get your object back into NSString or on any label this will be only "String" not any bracket.

Comment: Glad that was cleared up now just to understand what i need to do for the first part of my question should I add them to some sort of object to view in NSTable View or is there another way to go about it?

Comment: UITabelView need array kinda collection so that you can get the object based on the index, NSArray is preferred way but if you have unique object then you can use NSSet too

Comment: So theres no need to add them to an object as they are already in an array?

Comment: No, they are just fine :) pass into UITableView delegate and have fun

Comment: As per my knowledge, everything added to array is in form of object. So string is added as object too.

Comment: Yes, but array its self is also an object

Answer (score 0):

It is considering each object as an array. so you can use `[userFoodDataArray firstObject]`, it will return the first object. In your case the only onject it has.